# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined When sending a message in another channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have absolutely no idea why I am getting this, so maybe someone here might know.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

The code:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {

    if (msg.channel.id === '744422228996915230' || '754311827701104652') {
        if (msg.author.id === '744440671993200741') {
            return
        } else if (msg.channel.id === '744422228996915230' || '754311827701104652') {
            let messageAuthor = msg.author.username;
            let string = msg.content.toString();
            let splitString = string.split('|');
            let channelSendingTo = msg.guild.channels.cache.get(splitString[0]);
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(splitString[2]) //Normally #02055c
                .setTitle(splitString[3])
                .setDescription(splitString[4])
                .setImage(splitString[5])
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter('Sent by: ' + messageAuthor);

            channelSendingTo.send(splitString[1], embed);
        };

    };
});
```

**Important:** It gives the error when a message is sent in a channel other than the announcement sending channels and the channel the bot sends to. As soon as I talk in a channel other than those 2, it gives the error in the title.

Any help is appreciated, I really want to fix this issue I am having.
Updated Code to no longer have a double toString(). Edited code to be like what an answer said.

Comment: `channelSendingTo` would appear to be undefined; that would suggest `channelString` does not contain a valid channel.

Comment: this `client.channels.cache.get(channelString);` returns undefined and I think that is because channelString has the wrong value which seem plausible as you start here `let string = msg.toString();` to get that channelString. Given that `msg` is an object (by the looks of it) I doubt doing a toString on it is the right thing do. I expect you want some property of msg not msg itself.

Comment: The message to send to the announcement channel has this format:

744418310002573412|test|#02055c|test|test|https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/744418610163744818/760339655337312286/code_fix_working_2.png

Channel ID, ping, colour, title, description, image

Comment: @rene has a good point; why are you using `msg.channel.id` in the `if` but then `channelString` in the `get()`?

Comment: You send a message in one channel, and it embeds it into another channel. Looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/2bawRUk

Comment: oops, i forgot a very important part (now added)

Comment: if you do `console.log(msg.toString());` what do you get?

Comment: First I get the formatted message, and also the test announcement sent, and then once I send a message in another channel, in this case I sent 'test' I get the error on the next line in terminal. Output: https://imgur.com/a/tkxLQ1n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it could be for a number of reasons. First, you could be inputting the wrong channel id. Another very plausible reason is that you are doing `msg.ToString()`. Instead, you do `msg.content`, which gives what's inside the message. It is a better idea to get the channels from the guild(accessible from the message, with `msg.guild`).

Comment: I made the changes to the code that you said and it still errors when someone talks in another channel in the 2 servers the bot is in.

Comment: @MrLlamaDev one thing I have noticed is that the structure for your if statements seem a little odd. It checks if it is in a certain channel. If yes, it checks if the message was written by a specific person. If no, then it checks if it is those channels again?

Comment: I was just double checking to see if it's in the right channel as I thought that the rest of the code shouldn't run when a message is sent in another channel, but kind of does, because it only gives an error in another channel.

Comment: @MrLlamaDev so it only errors in channels that aren't id `744422228996915230` or `754311827701104652`? I'm a tad bit confused.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. I can talk in those channels without any error and the bot will turn my message into an announcement, but as soon as someone types in a channel that isn't one of those two, it will error and give that error message.

Comment: @MrLlamaDev then why would it be sending anything if it doesn't match the requirement to run .send anyway?

Comment: @MrLlamaDev I may have it! In the if statements you were doing `if (msg.channel.id === '744422228996915230' || '754311827701104652''`, instead of `if (msg.channel.id === '744422228996915230' || msg.channel.id === '754311827701104652'`. You were doing `if (string)`!

Comment: Works perfectly! Doesn't crash when | is said in a different channel now!

Comment: :D glad I could help!!